# select last row in mysql with no-auto incremental

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a temp logging database. Still on the learnig level.

How do I get the last row from the database?

```
select * from tempdat order by tdate desc limit 1
```

gives the first entry of the day but I want the last. See below, it could return the entry whit time `21:25:03`

```
+------------+----------+------+-------------+
| 2014-03-29 | 21:20:02 | inne |      22.875 |
| 2014-03-29 | 21:25:03 | inne |      22.875 |
+------------+----------+------+-------------+
1933 rows in set (0.16 sec)

mysql> select * from tempdat order by tdate desc limit 1;

+------------+----------+------+-------------+
| tdate      | ttime    | zone | temperature |
+------------+----------+------+-------------+
| 2014-03-29 | 00:00:03 | inne |      21.250 |
+------------+----------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two criteria for ordering: first `tdate`, then `ttime`. For example:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM tempdat 
  ORDER BY tdate DESC, ttime DESC 
     LIMIT 1;
```

Note that order direction should be specified after each column used. `ORDER BY tdate, ttime DESC` will first order all the records by `tdate ASC`.